# ArrayList inserting only single element

Tags: java, collections

```
ArrayList<Fix> fixList = new ArrayList<Fix>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(idlist, ",");
int index = 0;
while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
    Long id = Long.parseLong(st.nextElement().toString());          
    fixList.add(index++,fixManager.getFixById(id));
}
```

Arraylist here is able to take only one element. I debugged it, it takes only single element but count shows two or more elements are there in arraylist.

Comment: You don't add multiple element in ArrayList like that.. You could use a HashMap for what you want to achieve..

Comment: Please write input and output for the same

Comment: Just use `fixList.add(fixManager.getFixById(id));`

Comment: While debugging, are you looking at the internal array inside the ArrayList ? If so, that is preallocated with a length of 10 if you use the default constructor. Look at the `size` property to see how many elements are actually stored.

Comment: "it takes only single element but **count** shows two...". What is `count` ?

Comment: Thanks all. The answer is , even if the null is there arraylist will insert the element in itself and will increase the count .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the fixManager returns objects for each call? If you try to add null, ArrayList does not complains.

Answer (score 0):

why not just add the element, without defining the index?

```
fixList.add(fixManager.getFixById(id));
```

check out http://javafiddle.net/jqPDma

Comment: The effect is the same, so this couldn't be the actual problem, could it ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu if the effect were the same, then the problem is in `fixManager.getFixById(id)`.

Comment: ...or StringTokenizer has only one token

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashMap` for any kind of mapping you want..

```
Map<Integer, Fix> fixList = new HashMap<Integer, Fix>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(idlist, ",");
int index = 0;
while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
    Long id = Long.parseLong(st.nextElement().toString());          
    fixList.put(index++,fixManager.getFixById(id));
}
```

Or if you have `id` inside your `Fix` object.. You can simply add `2nd` element to your list.. You don't need to have an `index` for accessing them..

```
fixList.add(fixManager.getFixById(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct but your method

```
fixManager.getFixById(id)
```

inside loop is returning only one element based on that Id.

you can see, it by debugging the `getFixById(id)` inside your fixManager.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code

```
ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        x.add(i);
        x.add(i);

    }

    for(int i=0;i < x.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(x.get(i));
    }
```

and it works fine. so I think sou should check your getFixbyID() function. I doubt whether it is returning new Fix type object in each call.